# Compiler flags for checking Integer overflow

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, integer-overflow, type-promotion

In below program how do we make compiler to issue warning/error in case if there is going to be a problem with arithmetic expressions.

If an arithmetic expression is resulting into a value which exceeds the max value of their type i would like the compiler to issue warning/error.

I have compiled below program using `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)` and the compilation command used is `gcc int_promo_flags.c -Wall -Wextra`

I was expecting a warning/error from line `long long int y = x + INT_MAX;`, but there was no error/warning reported.

By casting `x` as `(long long) x` we can make the the expression to yeild correct value.
But are there any compiler flags to issue warning if the arithmetic expression is going to overflow its argument type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    long long int y = (long long) x + INT_MAX;
    printf("%lld\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long long` is probably far bigger (8 bytes) than `INT_MAX` (4 bytes) + 1 https://godbolt.org/z/GezYEcejj

Comment: The `long long` is a bit of a red herring, because the arithmetic will overflow anyway with those values, but for `int x = -1` it will not. It's up to the programmer to keep their eye on integer ranges. If that was in a function and `int x` was passed as an argument (its runtime value is unknown), would you expect a warning?

Comment: `int a, b; /* ... a>0, b>0 ... */ if (a > INT_MAX - b) fprintf(stderr, "a + b overflows\n");`

Comment: @WeatherVane, I agree with you , its difficult to track entire code(if it is big) personally for these problems. I was just curious if any flag available so it will make it easier :)

Comment: It's a matter of practice. If the arithmetic result is to be a larger type then you should know that it is expected to overflow. It's similar to the `int x=3, y=2; float z=x/y` gaffe.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `-ftrapv` flag in gcc - you can force your program to abort on integer overflow.

For instance, removing your cast and compiling with `-ftrapv`, your program aborts:

```
int x = 1;
long long int y = x + INT_MAX;
printf("%lld\n", y);
return 0;
```

```
> gcc main.c -ftrapv -o overflow
> ./overflow
fish: Job 1, './overflow' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

I don't think mainstream compilers support compile-time warning for signed integer overflows, but you can check for them manually at runtime.

Comment: yes , I saw the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow) ,`-ftrapv` is also mentioned there. Just wanted to know during compile time , if it can be detected.

Comment: @IrAM Unfortunately I don't think compilers provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Finding overflows using offline analysis is a complex algorithmic problem.
Likely Turing complete assuming infinite memory resources.

However, one can use a built-in sanitizers to find such overflows in runtime.

Just compile with `-fsanitize=undefined` option.
I've removed the cast because `INT_MAX` is not enough to overflow `long long`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    long long int y = x + INT_MAX;
    printf("%lld\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

The run produced following report:

```
prog.c:7:25: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1 + 2147483647 cannot be represented in type 'int'
-2147483648
```

There is a variety of sanitizer and the usually produce very good reports about violations.