# Is it possible to catch integer overflow exception in C (POSIX/Linux) via SIGFPE FPE_INTOVF?

Tags: c, linux, posix, integer-overflow, sigfpe

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I have found *zero* information about the topic (not here nor anywhere), so here's the question:

#### Context (what you probably already know): `SIGFPE` exceptions and `si_code` field

In POSIX/Linux we have a particular kind of signal called `SIGFPE` (that although its name, it's used both for floating-point and integer arithmetic errors). When we register a signal handler for `SIGFPE` using [`sigaction()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction), our handler also receives a field called `si_code` that explains why the particular `SIGFPE` exception has been raised. One of the possible `si_code` values is, for instance, `FPE_INTDIV`, and you can quickly test it by dividing an `int` by `0`.

#### The problem: what about `FPE_INTOVF`?

My question is about a particular `si_code`, that is **`FPE_INTOVF`**. This code is described as `Value signalling integer overflow in case of SIGFPE signal`.

The problem is that I have never encountered an example of this signal being raised, nor I found a way to make the OS raise this kind of signal: when I do an integer overflow in C, no `SIGFPE` exception is thrown. But the `FPE_INTOVF` value for `SIGFPE` is a kind of hint that it's maybe possible to make the host throw in case of integer overflows (like it already does for integer division by zero).

#### The question:

**Is `FPE_INTOVF` unusable? Is it just a place-holder for a type of signal that no POSIX-compliant OS has ever implemented? Or is it possible to instruct the OS to throw this kind of signal in case of integer overflow?**

I'm really interested in catching `FPE_INTOVF` signals from a C program using `sigaction()`.

---

P.S.: I recognize that unsigned integer overflow is not technically an error in C (it doesn't exist at all in C, since all unsigned integer arithmetic has "wrapping" behavior), but **signed** integer overflow is indeed undefined behavior, so I expect that `FPE_INTOVF` handles the latter.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/FPE_INTOVF - alpha ia64 m68k mips parisc s390 superh architectures. `Is FPE_INTOVF unusable?` what do you mean by "unusable"?

Comment: AFAIK, Posix defined that `si_code` value for completeness, but you're right, you'll never see it on common processors, since they don't trap on integer overflow at all.

Comment: Possibly related: [Compiler flags for checking Integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104632), [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333)

Comment: @KamilCuk Interesting, thanks. By the way, by "unusable" I meant that no OS implemented it, so you will never receive a signal of type `FPE_INTOVF`.

Comment: @SteveSummit I know how to detect overflow with other methods, I was just interested in `FPE_INTOVF` in particular. As KamilCuk found out, it appears that the signal is indeed supported, but only on specific architectures (at least on Linux, I don't know about other POSIX environments).

Comment: The point is that it needs the CPU to support such exceptions in the first place; it's a hardware feature that may or may not exist depending on the architecture.  And the details of exactly when the exception would be raised, and how you enable it, would also be system-specific.  It's certainly not going to provide you a nice reliable method for detecting integer overflow in general.  `gcc -ftrapv` is probably a better bet for that.

Comment: Another point as far as detecting overflow is that even if the hardware can trap on every possible integer arithmetic instruction that causes overflow (which may or may not be the case), there's also the compiler to consider, which knows that signed integer overflow is UB and might optimize it out, so that no trapping instruction ever gets executed.  Again `-ftrapv` would be better because it tells the compiler to define overflow as trapping.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I know about the UB optimization problem, and I have used `-ftrapv` oftentimes. I was just interested in a possible alternative with `FPE_INTOVF` (in the first place, I was just curious, since I've never seen it used in real life). I didn't realize it's too much tied to hardware support. I thought that maybe, with some compiler support, it would work on any CPU. But I think that `FPE_INTOVF` has simply been replaced by `-ftrapv` nowadays and nobody uses it anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure that the compiler could use `FPE_INTOVF` generically even if it wanted to.  It could test every arithmetic operation for overflow, but in case of overflow it can at best `raise(SIGFPE)` and there is no way to specify an `si_code`.  I think `si_code` can only come from the hardware, and POSIX just tried to provide constants corresponding roughly to every type of exception they were aware of actual hardware being able to produce, so that some sort of reporting mechanism could exist.

Comment: @NateEldredge FWIW, the host environment could have provided a special raise function so that the compiler may raise a `SIGFPE` specifying its `si_code`. But I guess neither Linux nor other POSIX environments provide such a function (a quick search may confirm my assumption). So yea, `FPE_INTOVF` is definitively meant to be used as a 1:1 mapping to a hardware integer overflow exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

Exceptions of type `SIGFPE FPE_INTOVF` appear to be thrown only when the underlying hardware has support for them. For instance, on Linux, these are the archs that may throw `FPE_INTOVF`: `alpha`, `ia64`, `m68k`, `mips`, `parisc`, `s390`, and `superh`.

#### Not an answer to my question, but worth noting:

My question was about `FPE_INTOVF` in particular, but if one just wants to check for integer overflow in general, it's worth noting that there are alternative ways to do so: compiler-specific functions like `__builtin_sadd_overflow()` ([read more here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)) or compiler-specific flags like `-ftrapv` on GCC. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104632) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333) related questions on SO.

#### Credits

I'd like to thank users [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk), [Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit) and [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) for their contributions to this answer through their comments.

---

P.S.: in case someone else wants to add other information about `FPE_INTOVF`, they may post another answer to this question, or they may write a comment to this very answer, and I will edit the answer to add the additional information.